# Cascade delete on entity expiry in Mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I have an entity defined by the following schema:

```
@Schema()
export class Bar extends Document {
//...
  @Prop({
    type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Foo' }],
    default: [],
  })
  foo: mongoose.Types.ObjectId[];

  @Prop({
    type: Date,
    expires: 86400, //expire in 1 day
    default: Date.now,
  })
  createdAt: Date;
//...
}
```

How can I make it so that all the "foo" entities related to this "bar" object be deleted once "bar" expires?

I was thinking of some kind of middleware that sets the expiry of "foo" objects related to "bar" to expire at the same time but I'm not sure how to go about this